# How can document references be used for Firestore API's [runQuery.startAt]?

Tags: firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore

When using the Firestore REST API to order and filter results, I am unable to use a cursor/reference value for the `startAt` value. I feel this may be possible, seeing it is provided in examples of Firestore's cursor-based pagination is detailed in their SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

I have a query that uses `orderBy` on a integer field within a document. I can successfully start at a specific integer value for this query, like so:

```
"structuredQuery": {
    "from": [
        {
            "collectionId": "objects"
        }
    ],
    "orderBy": [
        {
            "field": {
                "fieldPath": "counter"
            },
            "direction": "DESCENDING"
        }
    ],
    "startAt": {
        "values": [
            {
                "integerValue": 15
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm hoping to benefit from cursor pagination, but unfortunately if I change the `startAt` value to `referenceValue`, the query results do not reflect this, even though the query is successfully performed.

```
"startAt": {
    "values": [
        {
            "referenceValue": "projects/.../databases/(default)/documents/objects/OjvmBvvQ9TkyyQiJ4ExJ"
        }
    ]
}
```

Am I missing something in the way this works differently to the SDK examples?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to get it working ? I have the same issue, where using  "startAt": {
            "before": false,
            "values": [
                {
                    "referenceValue": "projects/{PROJECT-ID}/databases/(default)/documents/{COLLECTION-ID}/B"
                }
            ]
        }    doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that it's not a document reference but a document snapshot that you can use as a query cursor. A snapshot includes the field values needed for `startAt`. The SDKs take a document snapshot, extract the field values, and pass those values to `startAt`.

You can see the Node.js client library doing this here in [`createCursor`](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/blob/6c7a497aa1e42ee1e6876b6c8732f6f7d9c0062b/dev/src/reference.ts#L1458) and [`extractFieldValues`](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/blob/6c7a497aa1e42ee1e6876b6c8732f6f7d9c0062b/dev/src/reference.ts#L1137).

Comment: Oh, I see, interesting. So does that mean that a [startAt] result could include results from the previous query, if the value of the cursor's field matches other documents? Such as with an integer field within a small range, it is plausible for multiple documents to have the same value, yet due to result limiting they should be returning in separate sets.

Comment: The SDKs handle that case by [implicitly adding the document ID to the `orderBy`](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/blob/6c7a497aa1e42ee1e6876b6c8732f6f7d9c0062b/dev/src/reference.ts#L1399).